# Excel 2007 VBA - Cell value or ActiveX value which is better?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

My workbook has become so complicated that I want every formula / macro to be as efficient as possible which leads to my question -

Is it faster/more efficient to retrieve a value based on a worksheet cell value OR from an ActiveX object value?  I need this value regardless of what sheet the user is on in the workbook.

```
CStr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TearSheet").Range("SelectedCusip").Value2)
 '   or
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TearSheet").OLEObjects("cboCusipList").Object.Value
```

Does it even make a difference?  Thx much.

Comment: Retrieving one value is very fast and neither method should be noticeably faster; choose whichever seems to fit the rest of your code better. FWIW, I would rather pull a cell value. In general, focus your performance improvements where you are retrieving many values at a time or on the design of the worksheets themselves.

Comment: That's helpful... Thanks.  If you post it as an answer I'll give you credit for it.  Kinda new here so I don't know if that matters or not but I wanted to offer.

Comment: Have you tried to answer your own question by doing a simple test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieving one value is very fast and neither method should be noticeably faster; choose whichever seems to fit the rest of your code better. FWIW, I would rather pull a cell value. In general, focus your performance improvements where you are retrieving many values at a time or on the design of the worksheets themselves.